# Reading strings in C

Tags: c, string

I have to read strings of different length in C.I can do it using an array of pointers and using ,alloc inside the loop.The problem is that the input to the program is a series of sentences like this:

> Rene Decartes once said,
>   "I think, therefore I am."

and there can be many more. How can I check programmaticaly that the user has finished giving the input sentences.

Comment: Are you reading these strings from standard input, into this array of pointers? Or are you getting them through some other means which prepackages them into that array?

Comment: think of this like this ,what if I have to read in some sentences from the user at runtime without knowing how many sentences he will type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe he's even looking for the end-of-file (end of input, end of stream). You can detect the end of the input stream by checking the return value of various input functions. You did not tell us which function you use for reading input. E.g. with `fgets()` and input on standard input you would do

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 256
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
...

while (fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {
   /* Do something with buffer. */
}
/* No more lines on stdin. */
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, you're not looking for the "end of line" signal; you're looking for the "end of sentences" signal.

A common way to do this is to ask the user to enter an empty line when s/he's done.  Then (depending on how you're reading the strings), you can check for either an empty string, or a string with only a single (newline) character.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array keys until you find a "\0" character.

Comment: Hi Mario,after each sentence I can expecta '\0'

Comment: "\0" defines an end of a string. If you say `char something[] = "abc";` if would be an array of length 4 containing a, b, c and a \0. So yes, if it is a string, there would certainly be one.

Answer (score 0):

You should process them one line at a time using "end of line" as the delimiter.  You can store those into a `**char` -- properly allocated of course.  Do be careful of boundaries, and prefer `strncpy()` to `strcpy()` -- the later is unsafe.

Comment: think of this like this ,what if I have to read in some sentences from the user at runtime without knowing how many sentences he will type.Of course I can process it line by line but how will I know that the user is finished giving the input

Comment: Mark some delimiter as the end of the text.  OR use a time limit.  If after X seconds nothing has happened, then you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `some delimiters` and ask the user to enter it on finishing all the sentences,,
Also in-order to check for the end of `each line check with '\n' as the delimiter`,,

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the user to type in a special symbol or string which will indicate that the input has ended. For example you can tell the user to enter a `.` in a new line to terminate the input. Checkout @Adam Liss 's answer also.